# Uploading an Image instead of an UIImage to Firestore

Tags: ios, firebase, swiftui

Using Swift 5.0 / SwiftUI 2.0

One method available when uploading an UIImage to Firestore is jpegData(compressionQuality: Double) which essentially makes the whole process of fetching the saved image a lot faster.

Is there any equivalent for Image yet or any other viable workarounds or its as simple as either UIImage or poor UX

Comment: create a variable  typed UIImage then use it in SwiftUI like  Image(uiImage: image)

Comment: @Yodagama Yes, I’m aware of that functionality but I cannot go the other way around with that. Meaning I cannot do UIImage(image: image). The function you mentioned is good for converting the image once downloaded but I’m curious about uploading. There seems to be now way to upload with just SwiftUI just yet.

Comment: When you say `Image` what specifically do you mean? Also, what's the use case - is this for thumbnails or something else?

Comment: @Jay by Image I mean the Image type provided by the SwiftUI module. This particular use case is yes a thumbnail for a profile image but I didn’t want to limit to any one particular use case for the sake of scalability.

Comment: Well, if this is for thumbnails, Firebase has a really cool thumbnail generator cloud function that generates those on a server level. See [Cloud Storage Triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events). That lets the server do the heavy lifting and is super fast.

Comment: @Jay Thanks, much appreciated!

Comment: @SergioBost Question title should be like this -> How to convert SwiftUi Image view to data?

Answer (score 0):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    //Here
    @State var uiImage: UIImage?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if uiImage != nil {
                Image(uiImage: uiImage!)
            }
            
            
            Button(action: {
                downloadImage()
            }, label: {
                Text("Download image")
            })
        }
        
    }

    func downloadImage() {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:URL(string: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3f/Self-portrait_taken_with_laptop%2C_March%2C_2018.jpg")!) { (data, response, eooror) in
            guard data != nil else { return }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.uiImage = UIImage(data: data!)
            }
    
        }.resume()
    }
    
    //Here
    func getData() {
        var data = uiImage?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)
    }
}
```